# ASP.NET Web API help page - how to show generic return type in documentation

Tags: documentation, asp.net-web-api

I'm using a generic return type for all my api responses:

```
    public HttpStatusCode statusCode { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> errorfor { get; set; }
    public T result { get; set; }
```

and in API:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// GET Order API
 /// </summary>
 /// <returns> return list of orders {Order} </returns>

 public HttpResponseMessage Get(){
   var response = new BaseResponseMessage<IList<Order>>();
   //some more codes
   response.result = orders;
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
}
```

Now of course my API Help page don't show Order in sample Response body. Is it possible to configure Help Page generator to show generic type? Thanks!

Comment: I noticed you unanswered my reply, but how does that make sense...since my reply was more than 6 months old and 2 releases happened since then...answers have a time context, right? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not be possible for HelpPage to guess what would be the return type of an action with just the signature that you have. As you know HelpPage generation does not happen during normal request, but is something which depends on static information.

There is a workaround for this though. You can look at the following commented code in `Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs` which lets you specify a specific return type for an action.

```
 //// Uncomment the following to correct the sample response when the action returns an HttpResponseMessage with ObjectContent<string>.
 //// The sample will be generated as if the controller named "Values" and action named "Post" were returning a string.
 //config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(string), "Values", "Post");
```

I understand that this workaround would be too cumbersome for you since you mentioned about having this kind of signature for all your actions.

You could probably extend HelpPage by creating a custom attribute which informs about the return type and decorate it on the actions. You can then modify installed HelpPage code to look for these attributes.

Answer (score 20):

Web API 2.1 Help Pages now do this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21#help-page

You might also check out returning the standard HttpResponseMessage with the new [ResponseTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.responsetypeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// GET Order API
/// </summary>
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Order>))]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var orders = new List<Order>();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, orders);
}
```

Comment: Note of caution to anyone who tries this: as of 2.1 this works but it seems to break (for me at least) if your generic class has a public non-default constructor.

Comment: Found a workaround for my above issue: ensure the model has a public default constructor. See http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1480

Comment: Worked Great. Nice simple way to do it. And worked for my complex objects as well.

Comment: You need to add: `using System.Web.Http.Description;` to use this attribute.